# Sending multidimensional array from jQuery to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I am passing an array from jQuery to php.

The array is generated from a table with this code:

```
    var stitchChartArray = [];
    var row = 0;

    // turn stitch chart into array for php
    $('#stitchChart').find('tr').each(function (index, obj) {

        //first row is table head- "Block #"
        if(index != 0){
            stitchChartArray.push([]);
            var TDs = $(this).children();
            $.each(TDs, function (i, o) {
                var cellData = [$(this).css('background-color'), $(this).find("img").attr('src')];
                stitchChartArray[row].push(cellData);
            });
            row++;
        }

    });
```

In console it looks like this:

```
[[["rgb(75, 90, 60)", "symbols/177.png"], ["rgb(75, 75, 60)", "symbols/184.png"], ["rgb(75, 90, 60)", "symbols/177.png"], 7 more...], [["rgb(105, 105, 105)", "symbols/163.png"], ["rgb(75, 75, 60)", "symbols/184.png"], ["rgb(75, 90, 60)", "symbols/177.png"], 7 more...], [["rgb(105, 105, 105)", "symbols/163.png"], ["rgb(75, 90, 60)", "symbols/177.png"], ["rgb(75, 75, 60)", "symbols/184.png"], 7 more...], [["rgb(75, 90, 60)", "symbols/177.png"], ["rgb(75, 90, 60)", "symbols/177.png"], ["rgb(98, 119, 57)", "symbols/210.png"], 7 more...], [["rgb(105, 105, 105)", "symbols/163.png"], ["rgb(105, 105, 105)", "symbols/163.png"], ["rgb(150, 150, 195)", "symbols/72.png"], 7 more...], [["rgb(75, 165, 105)", "symbols/187.png"], ["rgb(134, 158, 134)", "symbols/64.png"], ["rgb(165, 180, 180)", "symbols/171.png"], 7 more...], [["rgb(60, 150, 75)", "symbols/189.png"], ["rgb(120, 120, 90)", "symbols/225.png"], ["rgb(143, 163, 89)", "symbols/209.png"], 7 more...]]
```

It represents each row of a table->each cell of row->[0]rgb value of bg of cell [1]icon in cell.

This jQuery code returns the correct element(and rgb value) from the array:

```
alert(stitchChartArray[1][1][0]); //row 1,cell 1, first value(rgb)
```

But when it gets sent to the php script with this:

```
$.post('makeChartPackage.php', {'stitchChart[]': stitchChartArray }, function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
```

The php throws an error:

> Cannot use string offset as an array in /Users/tnt/Sites/cross_stitch/makeChartPackage.php on line 33

```
$stitchChart = $_POST['stitchChart']; 
echo $stitchChart[1][1][0]; //line 33
```

I am assuming I am either constructing the array incorrectly or passing it to the php script incorrectly.

**EDIT:**
I did this to return the array to jQuery:

```
$stitchChart = $_POST['stitchChart'];
print_r($stitchChart);
```

And here was the result:
Array
(
    [0] => rgb(75, 90, 60),symbols/177.png,rgb(75, 75, 60),symbols/184.png,rgb(75, 90, 60),symbols/177.png,rgb(98, 119, 57),symbols/210.png,rgb(180, 195, 105),symbols/388.png,rgb(165, 165, 120),symbols/235.png,rgb(75, 75, 60),symbols/184.png,rgb(90, 90, 45),symbols/195.png,rgb(120, 120, 75),symbols/156.png,rgb(105, 105, 105),symbols/163.png
    [1] => rgb(105, 105, 105),symbols/163.png,rgb(75, 75, 60),symbols/184.png,rgb(75, 90, 60),symbols/177.png,rgb(75, 90, 60),symbols/177.png,rgb(165, 165, 120),symbols/235.png,rgb(120, 120, 75),symbols/156.png,rgb(75, 90, 60),symbols/177.png,rgb(75, 90, 60),symbols/177.png,rgb(105, 105, 105),symbols/163.png,rgb(120, 120, 90),symbols/225.png
    [2] => rgb(105, 105, 105),symbols/163.png,rgb(75, 90, 60),symbols/177.png,rgb(75, 75, 60),symbols/184.png,rgb(75, 90, 60),symbols/177.png,rgb(98, 119, 57),symbols/210.png,rgb(75, 90, 60),symbols/177.png,rgb(75, 75, 60),symbols/184.png,rgb(105, 105, 105),symbols/163.png,rgb(120, 120, 90),symbols/225.png,rgb(105, 105, 105),symbols/163.png

It appears the array is not multidimensional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['stitchChart']` in the context you have addressed it there is (effectively) a JSON representation of a multidimensional array, stored as a string. When you treat a string as a multidimensional indexed array in PHP, you will get that error. The first `[x]` is treated as a "string offset" - i.e. the character at position `x` - but the next and any subsequent `[x]` addresses can only be treated as arrays (you cannot get a substring of a single character) and will emit the error you have received.

To access your data as an array in PHP, you need to use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$stitchChart = json_decode($_POST['stitchChart'],TRUE); 
echo $stitchChart[1][1][0];
```

**EDIT**

Because the jQuery `data` argument seemingly can't deal with multidimensional arrays, you should use Douglas Crockford's [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library and pass the result into `data` as a string. NB: use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Here is how you could do this:

```
stitchChartArray = JSON.stringify(stitchChartArray);
$.post('makeChartPackage.php', {'stitchChart': stitchChartArray }, function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

If you use this code, my original PHP suggestion should work as expected.

Comment: I thought that was going to be it! But now I am getting an error: PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Users/tnt/Sites/cross_stitch/makeChartPackage.php on line 34

Comment: no matter what I do the array seems to be getting flattened down to just one dimension: array[0]"a string" [1]"a string"etc. when it should be: array[0][0]"rgb color" [1]"symbol path" [1][0]"rgb color"[1]"symbol path"

Comment: Tried that and almost the same error: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Users/tnt/Sites/cross_stitch/makeChartPackage.php on line 29. Un jsoned the array looks a bit different: Array
(
    [0] => [[[\"rgb(75, 90, 60)\",\"symbols/177.png\"],[\"rgb(75, 75, 60)\",\"symbols/184.png\"],[\"rgb(75, 90, 60)\",\"symbols/177.png\"],[\"rgb(98, 119, 57)\",\"symbols/210.png\"],[\"rgb(180, 195, 105)\",\"symbols/388.png\"],[\"rgb(165, 165, 120)\",\"symbols/235.png\"],[\"rgb(75, 75, 60)\",\"symbols/184.png\"],[\"rgb(90, 90, 45)\",\"symbols/195.png\"],[\"rgb(120, 1...

Comment: @maddogandnoriko you need to remove the `[]` from your Javascript - I suspect that if you examine the difference between your code and mine, you'll find that you have `stitchChart[]` where I just have `stitchChart`

Comment: I will have to some more research on this, and I do not want to take up all of your time, on a related note you may be able to help me work around this...how much more 'overhead' is it going to cost me to just make two 'non dimensional' arrays and pass them? It is not the best solution, but will get me by for now. Or is that just the total wrong thing to do?

Comment: I do think that my previous suggestion should fix your problem - but if you do `$stitchChart = json_decode($_POST['stitchChart'][0],TRUE);` it should also work - although the best think to do is to prevent it from being turned into an array in the first place. Search for unecessary `[]`s in you Javascript...

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much, your a wizard. I am getting a warning that this is getting extended...but for the sake of a complete answer...I did research on this before I drug you into it and as far as I could find jQuery 1.4 and up were supposed to automagically handle multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @maddogandnoriko I was under this impression also, but the results you get seem to indicate to the contrary. You could try passing them as objects, but I sort of doubt this would fix it... But really, I would say that JSON is the way this sort of thing *should* be done anyway, especially when working in Javascript, the language from which JSON derives it's syntax...